# Buy NFT with fee for the marketplace

Tags: smart-contracts, nft, blockchain

I want when a user buys an nft, 90% of the amount goes to the author and 10% to the marketplace.

When I deploy my smart contract everything works fine: https://legacy.smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmWDHLWSQYKJSRPbvLWqPc41BZtJ8X7svQgEDnrtckQiHt&k=d5825d30041e66cfc3a4

When I call the smart contract function in react js:

```
export const collectNFT = ({ Tezos, amount, id, author }) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const contract = await Tezos.wallet.at(config.contractAddress);
      const op = await contract.methods
        .collect(id)
        .send({ mutez: true, amount: amount });
      await op.confirmation();
      dispatch(fetchData());
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};
```

I get an error when confirming on my wallet:

```
{
  "error": [
    {
      "errors": [
        {
          "kind": "temporary",
          "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.runtime_error",
          "contract_handle": "KT1JB3JUsvwxrHc6W93ZpWwkKSD3xQGy7waL",
          "contract_code": "Deprecated"
        },
        {
          "kind": "temporary",
          "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.script_rejected",
          "location": 152,
          "with": {
            "int": "83"
          }
        }
      ],
      "errorDetails": "Error occurred during estimation",
      "name": "TezosOperationError",
      "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.script_rejected",
      "kind": "temporary",
      "message": "83",
      "isError": true
    },
    {
      "errors": [
        {
          "kind": "temporary",
          "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.runtime_error",
          "contract_handle": "KT1JB3JUsvwxrHc6W93ZpWwkKSD3xQGy7waL",
          "contract_code": "Deprecated"
        },
        {
          "kind": "temporary",
          "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.script_rejected",
          "location": 152,
          "with": {
            "int": "83"
          }
        }
      ],
      "errorDetails": "Error occurred during estimation",
      "name": "TezosOperationError",
      "id": "proto.016-PtMumbai.michelson_v1.script_rejected",
      "kind": "temporary",
      "message": "83",
      "isError": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to know where my error comes from and why.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error, it was necessary to put an empty field in "entry_point"

```
token_contract = sp.contract(sp.TUnit, self.data.data[params.token_id].author, entry_point="").open_some()

marketplace_contract = sp.contract(sp.TUnit, self.data.admin, entry_point="").open_some()
```

Don't forget to put yourself as admin to receive the 10%